# VBA filter then copy rows to a new sheet ? excel 2007

Tags: excel, vba

I need a way to copy rows with data what has been filter user auto-filter

My problem is i dont know why but when VBA copy's and paste data from a filter it makes both of the sheets row limit go all the way down to the max. Making my file size way bigger, and taking longer bc of the added size

```
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$B:$B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Dump").Select
    Cells.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Only thing i have found to deal with this is to

```
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$B:$B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"

   'some how Copy all rows with data'

    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Dump").Select
    Cells.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

I have tested out copying the rows without VBA and it did work without any errors but i dont know how to code VBA to do that so what im asking 
How to copy the rows that have been filter or if u happen to know away around the size limit problem that would be nice to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet

    Set wsData = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDest = Sheets("Dump")

    With wsData.Range("B1", wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter 1, "<>"
        .CurrentRegion.Copy wsDest.Range("A1")
        .AutoFilter
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That only copy the first row how would i get the number of how many rows there is so i can turn your

 .CurrentRegion.Copy wsDest.Range("A1")

into a loop

Comment: ? This doesn't just copy the first row, it would copy all visible rows.  I have tested it and it works just fine for me.  Do you have full rows that are just blank cells breaking up your data? That's about the only thing that would mess up the `CurrentRegion`

Comment: yeah but why does the auto filter not take care of the blank rows ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work in 2007 but I can only test it in 2013 (and it worked).  Try to use the paste special "SkipBlanks" option:

```
ActiveSheet.Columns("B:B").AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$B:$B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
ActiveSheet.Columns("B:B").Copy
Sheets("Dump").Columns("B:B").PasteSpecial SkipBlanks:=True
```